# Definitive way to find out what Spring context/config file scans a particular bean?

Tags: spring

There is a bean, let's say `org.foo.bar.Bean` annotated with `@Component` so that it gets scanned by Spring via `component-scan` in xml or `@ComponentScan` in java config. The problem is that the artifact, in which the bean resides, let's say artifact A, has multiple component scans with overlapping packages. On top of that, it has 3 dependencies (B, C and D), which of them scans classpath of artifact A, fully or partially, and all those scanned beans are combined into one huge Spring context.

Is there a way to determine what particular xml or java config file(s) from A, B, C or D picked the Bean during scanning? If there are more than one, I need to find all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) to retrieve the [`resourceDescription`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html#getResourceDescription--) of the bean, a description of the resource that this bean definition came from:

```java
@Component
public class ExampleBFPP implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleBFPP.class);

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory clbf) throws BeansException {
        log.info("Resource description: {}", clbf.getBeanDefinition("springBeanId").getResourceDescription());
    }
}
```

Note that the Spring bean ID can be;

- the explicitly given name of the bean by using the `id` attribute in XML,
- the explicitly given name of the bean using `@Bean("name")` or `@Bean(name="name")`
- the lower camel case name of the `@Bean` method name,
- or the lower camel class name of the bean class.

In your case; `bean`.

Comment: I tried it - it just printed path to the bean itself, not to the configuration. I think it'll work only for explicitly declared beans via `@Bean`, but that's not my case. The bean I'm interested in is annotated with stereotype annotation - `@Component`.